# What is the proper way to proceed after a closed question?

Tags: discussion, migration, reopen-closed

After having [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10524653/594137) closed which I thought belonged on SO, I reworded it to make it more objective.

There was some speculation in comments about where it belonged and I am still not sure. Is it worth rolling back that question to the state when it was closed, then asking the reworded version on Programmers? Or is there a procedure for migrating a closed question and reopening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your revision will effectively "bump" up the question and cause it to get some new views. Many  of those users will have privileges to vote to re-open your question, and if enough of them agree, your question will be automatically re-opened. At the time of this writing, 3 people have already voted to re-open your question, so the system appears to be working.

If you've given it a day or so and your question *still* hasn't been re-opened (but you've honestly put some effort into revising it and followed the advice of commenters), you can flag it for moderator attention and ask that it be re-opened. Use the "other" option and fill in the free-form textbox with an explanation of your situation. Keep in mind that moderators process *lots* of flags each day, and the more compelling that your explanation is, the better your chances are that they'll agree with you.

As far as migration goes, you're better off re-asking the question on another site. That gives you an opportunity to check out their FAQ and compose/revise your question accordingly. There's little point in re-opening a question on one site just so that it can be migrated to another site. And there's even less point in flagging it for a moderator to migrate, since they're just going to have to confer with the moderators on the proposed target site to see if the question is even a good fit for them. You can leave out the middle man by doing that legwork yourself.