# Temporary measure re informing users about prospects for reopening closed questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, closed-questions, close-reasons

I see (several|many) questions on meta.stackoverflow.com asking about the closing of specific questions, getting similar responses. Also, there are [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132060/196834) and perhaps a few others which are the meta-discussion of the same issue, with answers explaining a procedure, or approach, or conditions, for questions being reopened. However, just looking at the box which opens up when your question was closed, you have practically no way of guessing that information.

Several suggestions appear [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120372/196834), such as changing the FAQ, creating a special guide, etc. While that is being debated and worked on, perhaps a link from the closed question box to one of the meta pages I've linked to could serve as a temporary measure?

Comment: If your question gets closed, there is a link to the FAQ within the closure message. The second and third line of that FAQ entry are *"Closed questions cannot be answered, but are eligible for improvement (and eventual re-opening) through editing, voting, and commenting. See How to Ask for guidance on editing your question to improve it."*...that pretty much says all, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't: It doesn't mention flagging for review; it can be easily interpreted as "if you edit the question, then the specific users who closed it might reconsider"; it is not at all clear who's supposed to do the voting and commenting; etc.

Comment: Flagging for review is a last measure. The community should ideally handle this on its own without involving moderators. And as always, voting and commenting are community activities as well. I'm not saying it can't be improved, but there is already a reasonable amount of information out there to get you started.

Comment: I think you find the information sufficient because you have the rich context of how such a process would happen. That creates a sort of a bias. As a new user, I feel that the information is lacking in breadth and in explicitness.

Comment: That might be. I also think it's part *"I'm not going to read the message, nor the FAQ. I'm going to ask people"*, but you might have a point.